# Associated primes of powers of a monomial ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

> Let $I\subset K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a monomial ideal, $t\ge 2$ an integer, and $\mathfrak p‎ ‎‎\in \operatorname{‎Ass}(R/‎I^t)$. ‎Then one knows that $‎\mathfrak p=(I^t :‎ ‎c)‎$ for some ‎monomial $‎c‎‎\in ‎R$.‎ Show that $c\in I^{t-1}$.

Since $\mathfrak p$ is necessarily a monomial prime ideal it is generated by a subset of the variables, and $x_ic ‎\in ‎I^t‎$ for a variable ‎$x_i‎\in\mathfrak p$‎ ‎then $c‎ ‎‎\in ‎I^{t-1}‎$. I ‎can't ‎understand ‎‎why.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $I$ is generated by the monomials $m_1,\dots,m_r$. Then $I^t$ is generated by all the products of $t$ (not necessarily distinct) monomials from the set $\{m_1,\dots,m_r\}$. The ideal $(I^t:c)$ is generated by the monomials $m_{i_1}\cdots m_{i_t}/\gcd(m_{i_1}\cdots m_{i_t},c)$ and since this ideal is also generated by a subset of variables, then there is an $i$ such that $$X_i=\frac{m_{i_1}\cdots m_{i_t}}{\gcd(m_{i_1}\cdots m_{i_t},c)}.$$ Now we get $\gcd(m_{i_1}\cdots m_{i_t},c)=\frac{m_{i_1}\cdots m_{i_t}}{X_i}$ $\Rightarrow$ $X_i\mid m_{i_1}\cdots m_{i_t}$ and $\frac{m_{i_1}\cdots m_{i_t}}{X_i}\mid c$ $\Rightarrow$ $c\in I^{t-1}.$

Comment: can you explain me clearly about monomial generators of colon ideal as above